# How send hyperlink embed into a string in Telegram with bot?

Tags: c#, api, telegram-bot

I want to understand if it's possible and how do it: "How send a hyperlink into the word in the Telegram."
I'm using Telegram API and if I try to send a Link string it appears like "https://www.google.it/" and not like [Link](https://www.google.it).

Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, next after me, can try this.

```
Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(yourChatId, yourMessage, parseMode: Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ParseMode.Html)
```

Answer (score 0):

When we using TelegramBotClient, we can show links on buttons. I do it with the markdown type

```
var text = $"Select search engine mode";
var inlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
            new[]
            {
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("System 1",  $"https://google.com/"),
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("System 2",  $"https://yandex.ru/")
            });

await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    yourChatId,
                    text,
                    replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard,
                    parseMode: ParseMode.Markdown)
```